# SQL used in GIS Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT' SQL GIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I keep getting this error message

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

This is my SQL code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(DATETIME, CNS_STATUS_DATE), 101) AS CNS_STATUS_DATE,
```

Comment: Can you past your complete query and also tag the database you are using. And explain what exactly you are doing

Answer (score 0):

you have to write all the fields that you want to be on the new table before the FROM clause.

based on your query, maybe something like this?

```
SELECT CNS_PID, CNS_BID, CNS_STYLE, CNS_BASE_RATE, CNS_STYLE_DESC, CNS_IS_CMRCL, CNS_IS_CONDO, CNS_IS_CONDO_MAIN, CNS_MDL, CNS_MDL_DESC, CNS_IS_VACANT, CNS_SIZ_ADJ_FACTOR, CNS_AREA_EFFECTIVE, CNS_AREA_GROSS, CNS_AREA_LIVING, CNS_REPLACE_COST, CNS_APPRAIS_VAL, CNS_REAL_APPRAIS_VAL, CNS_ASSESS_VAL, CNS_REAL_ASSESS_VAL, CNS_OVERRIDE_VAL, CNS_OVERRIDE_INITIALS, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(datetime, CNS_STATUS_DATE), 101) AS CNS_STATUS_DATE, CNS_REGRESSION_VAL, CNS_OCC, CNS_OCC_DESC, CNS_BLDG_STORIES, CNS_GROUP, CNS_STRUCT_CLASS INTO VISION_CONSTR FROM [VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[CONSTR]
```